# How to rename muliple files in SFTP using BASH script

Tags: bash, sftp

I am a beginner to shell scripting.
I am trying to rename multiple files using wildcard in SFTP.

Please provide me some solution. or suggest some idea

My sh script:

```
sftp  $userName@$hostName <<EOF
lcd  $downloadPath
cd $rootpath
rename  *.txt  $rootpath/*.txt
exit
EOF
```

For this I got below error:

```
couldnt rename : no such file directory
```

Comment: HI Kamil, I added  more details.

Comment: Are you bound to bash? If not, I'd looking into the Python 'paramiko' module, this can do it quite easily.

Comment: but i not knowing python scripting

Comment: Do not be afraid to learn new scripting languages. There are good examples out there. One of them is: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_sftp.py

Comment: Since you seem to only want to move directories, there are graphical file managers (such as Dolphin) that can transparently access files via SFTP, and then moving the files can just be done by drag and drop. Alternatively, if you can access the files via SFTP you likely have access to the host via SSH so you can issue plain shell command in an SSH terminal session.

Answer (score 1):

The `sftp` client is fairly basic, and won't execute loops or substitute variables. You have to

- Issue a first SFTP command that does a `ls` of the directory, and capture its output
- process that output to generate the list of rename command for each file
- Issue a second SFTP command with execute that list of rename commands

All in all, the alternatives are likely simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The following script is for FTP command. you can modify it to work with SFTP 
The concept is generate a todo file to rename(move) each file one by one 
full script to achieve move more than one file 
1. get file list from ftp server with mls command 
2. generate to do list file 
2.1 get file 
2.2 rename (move file) 
3. execute ftp command with to do list file

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
# change local directory
cd [local-directory]

#collect file names
ftp -ni ftp.abccompany.com <<EOF
user [user] [password]
cd /OUT
mls abc*.* list.txt 
quit
EOF

# create ftp action list
echo >>todo.lst user [user] [password]
while read N
do
    echo >>todo.lst cd /OUT
    echo >>todo.lst get $N
    echo >>todo.lst rename $N ARCHIVE/$N
done <list.txt

echo >>todo.lst quit

# ftp transfer process
ftp -nv ftp.abccompany.com <todo.lst

# cleanup
rm todo.lst
```